# Using PubNub, is Unsubscribe a dual use command for Publish and Subscribe?

Tags: pubnub

Yes, I know it seems like a simple question but I just recently started using PubNub and I am confused on how to disconnect from a channel. I think the command to use is "Unsubscribe" and my misunderstanding relates to the dual use of the word.

Logically, I understand that once you initialize PubNub and publish a message a separate process can subscribe to the establish channel. When it's done it unsubscribes. Got it!

Now we want to completely disconnect from PubNub. That is end the channel.
Do I use the command "Unsubscribe" to do this? I guess I am logically looking for an "End" or "Disconnect" command and not an  "Unsubscribe" command because it did not subscribe to the channel, it established the channel. I know it seems petty but until I understand this it's difficult to move forward. So is this a dual use command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track here. Depending on the client platform in question, an unsubscribe resulting in an empty channel list will completely disconnect you.

On the more sophisticated clients, advanced/smart frameworks, there are the API calls of un/subscribe (which as you described subs /unsubs you to a specific channel), and  separately, the public and/or private method calls defining/detecting being "connected" or "online".

For example, iOS has specific connect and disconnect calls, separate from subscribe/unsubscribe calls.  On JS, there is no explicit connect/disconnect, but regardless if you are subbed or not to an active channel list, there may be background "pings/heartbeats" being made to the PN cloud to detect connectivity/online/offline state.

If you give more info on the client platform and version you are on, we can give you more info on how to completely sever all connects to the PN cloud and achieve a "complete disconnect".

geremy

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0, C#, VS2010, and the latest version of PubNub.

Comment: In response to your answer, are you saying that even if the last task to unsubscribe from the channel is not the original creator of the channel that will result in an empty channel list that will completely disconnect you?  In other words it really does not matter which task is last to unsubscribe, it's just that there is an empty channel and that alone results in the disconnect! Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question 100%, but Connect/Disconnect would be analogous to "establish/destroy a network connection to PubNub cloud". Subscribe/Unsubscribe are things you can only do once you are connected.

What is the end-result of the operation you are looking for? Are you looking to just no longer subscribe/receive data from a remote publisher(s) ? Or are you looking for an even lower-level objective -- to not receive any subscribe traffic on any channels, and be sure that the network connections to the PubNub cloud are severed from the computer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay to your response, I am on jury duty. Your answer was very helpful. Thanks again.